# How can I debug TypeScript (Angular 2+) from Electron window app?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, electron, webstorm

I would like to debug TypeScript code (Angular 2+) from Electron js window inside VS code or WebStorm.

In WebStorm I tried "Attach to Node.js/Chrome", I can see debug log inside WebStorm console but breakpoints placed into TypeScript don't work.

I'm able to debug Electron js main process (Electron main.js is compiled from main.ts file, so the debug of TypeScript works) but I don't understand how to debug Angular's TypeScript code from Wlectron window.

I know that I could run my Angular app into the browser and debug it from there but the project is based on Electron operations, so the app from browser cannot work correctly.

Electron app loads url of Angular Live Development Server
`win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');`

---

**EDIT:**
I started Angular dev server on `localhost:4200`, then I set `--remote-debugging-port=9222` for Electron app and finally Chrome is attached to port `9222`.

I can see the debug log of Chrome in VSCode and WebStorm but breakpoints placed in TypeScript not working. `"sourceMap": true` is placed in tsconfig.json.

In WebStorm I can see the following error that VSCode doesn't show me:

```
inspector.htmlAccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4200/scripts.js.map' from origin 'http://localhost:9222' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-ijt is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
http://…devtools/shell.js:8GET http://localhost:4200/scripts.js.map net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Running into the same issue, did you find a fix?